# Horizontal enumeration in multiple columns

Tags: lists, enumerate, tabbing

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{inparaenum}
\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text   
\end{inparaenum}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

It does exactly what I want, but I was wondering whether it was possible to create an environment, say `tabbedEnum` so that we can eliminate the use of the `\tab`, in particular, that the first case doesn't need a tab but all others do. Something of the form:

```
\begin{tabbedEnum}[3]
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{tabbedEnum}
```

Comment: If `enumitem` package is an option, then you can tweak the answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46665/multiple-choices-questions-in-2-or-3-columns to your liking

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just redefine `\item` to do what you want, but after the first use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\endinparaenum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbedenum}{3}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{tabbedenum}

\bigskip

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{inparaenum}
\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text   
\end{inparaenum}

\end{document}
```

Since we are using the original `\item` command at the end, you can also use the optional argument after `\item`.

[image]

Comment: That's cleverer than mine :)

Comment: That's a very elegant solution!

Comment: @cgnieder Minimalism. :)

Comment: How to add package enumerate inside like this 
1) tex    2) Tex     3) Tex ...

Answer (score 9):

Well, you can define your own environment that uses some `\inner@tab` that redefines itself on first use to call `\tab` and redefines `\item` to call `\inner@tab` before it issues the *real* `\item`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tabbedEnum}[1][3]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{\NumTabs{3}}{\NumTabs{#1}}%
  \inparaenum
    \let\orig@item\item
    \def\inner@tab{\let\inner@tab\tab}%
    \renewcommand\item[1][]{%
      \inner@tab\ifblank{##1}{\orig@item}{\orig@item[##1]}}%
    \ignorespaces
}{%
  \endinparaenum
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tabbedEnum}
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
\end{tabbedEnum}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative you could use [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)' `{tasks}` environment. It does not look exactly the same, though. Anyway, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

% \NewTasks[options]{name}[separator](default number of columns)
% all arguments except {name} are optional
\NewTasks[label=tsk.]{tabbedEnum}[\item](3)

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabbedEnum}
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
\end{tabbedEnum}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the `tasks` environment from `exsheets`! Note that it is now available as a standalone package, `tasks`. Thanks for pointing this out, it also solved an old problem of mine for formatting worksheets: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133330/multicolumn-list-with-same-number-of-items-in-each-column

Comment: when I copy-paste your MWE for the second solution (using exsheets), I get an array, but it's not enumerated, it just says "tsktext      tsktext     tsktext" etc. Any ideas? Literal copy-paste, so I'm at a loss.