# From paralist to enumitem, using tabto too

Tags: enumitem, paralist, tabto

This is a follow up question to the one I asked a while back: [Horizontal enumeration in multiple columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/horizontal-enumeration-in-multiple-columns) .

There I was using `paralist` and now I feel it is better to switch to `enumitem` (since I can use the `resume` option). The environment `tabbedenum` using `paralist` worked perfectly for my needs, but transferring this to `Tabbedenum` based on `enumitem` no longer works.

Could this be because of the star (i.e. if `\enumerate` is short for `\begin{enumerate}` then what works for `\begin{enumerate}*`)? That's why I tried by defining the environment `Inparaenum`.

Could the problem be based on the optional options? In fact, could `Tabbedenum` be defined with the optional options too, so that the syntax would be: `\begin{Tabbedenum}[label=\emph{\alph*})]{3}`?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{paralist}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\endinparaenum}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newenvironment{Inparaenum}{\begin{enumerate*}[label=\emph{\alph*})]}{\end{enumerate*}}

\newenvironment{Tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\Inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\endInparaenum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbedenum}{3}
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\end{tabbedenum}

\begin{Tabbedenum}{3}
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\end{Tabbedenum}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually a lot simpler with `enumitem`.  Essentially you can just use the `itemjoin` option to produce the tabbing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{Tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\begin{enumerate*}[label=\emph{\alph*}),itemjoin={\tab}]}{\end{enumerate*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Tabbedenum}{3}
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\end{Tabbedenum}

\end{document}
```

If you also want the first item placed at a tab stop then you can add `before={\tab}`:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{Tabbedenum}[1]
{\NumTabs{#1}\begin{enumerate*}[label=\emph{\alph*}),
before={\tab},itemjoin={\tab}]}{\end{enumerate*}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
My items:
\begin{Tabbedenum}{3}
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\end{Tabbedenum}

\end{document}
```

If there is no text before the list you will have to back up to hit the first tab stop, e.g. by issuing

```
\noindent\hspace{-10pt}
```

before the list or setting

```
before={\unskip\hspace{\dimexpr-\parindent-1pt}\tab}
```

You can pass optional arguments to such contstructs as in the following code.  Note that because of the grouping, `resume` needs to be combined with `series` to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{Tabbedenum}[2][]
{\NumTabs{#2}\begin{enumerate*}[label=\emph{\alph*}),
before={\unskip\hspace{\dimexpr-\parindent-1pt}\tab},itemjoin={\tab},#1]}%
{\end{enumerate*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Tabbedenum}[series=test]{3}
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\end{Tabbedenum}

\begin{Tabbedenum}[resume=test]{4}
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\item hello world
\end{Tabbedenum}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample resume]

Comment: This is great. I tried to pass some optional arguments as follows: `\newenvironment{Tabbedenum}[2][label=\emph{\alph*}]
{\NumTabs{#2}\begin{enumerate*}[
before={\unskip\hspace{\dimexpr-\parindent-1pt}\tab},itemjoin={\tab},#1]}{\end{enumerate*}}` but this gives errors, which disappear when I remove the `\unskip`. Can this be circumvented? Do I need the `\unskip`?

Comment: Just to add, I tried to optionally include `resume` but that didn't work.

Comment: I have now added code to show how to cope with optional arguments.  The `\unskip` is not giving me errors, but could be removed without affecting the given examples.

Comment: Your last solution works and even with the `\unskip` there are no errors. Many thanks for your effort!