# Rearrange How Multicol Lists Things

Tags: multicol

If I compile the following:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}

    \item Math

    \item Is 

    \item Quite

    \item Fun

\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
```

Then it will compile as:

```
     (a) Math   (c)  Quite

     (b) Is     (d) Fun
```

I would like (b) to be to the right of (a).  Is there any way to get Mulitcols to do this automatically?  I know I can just rename things or type them in a different order.

Comment: No, multicols creates columns. You should try enumitem or tabto:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122067/from-paralist-to-enumitem-using-tabto-too/122070#122070,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/horizontal-enumeration-in-multiple-columns

Comment: If you are preparing an exercise sheet, take a look at »[exsheets](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)«. It can arrange answers in the way you are looking for.