# Multicolumn list with same number of items in each column

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate, multicol

I want to make a multicolumn list with the same number of items in each column. I tried this with multicols, but some items have bigger heights than others so I got a column of 5 and a column of 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $1$
\item $2$
\item $3$
\item $4$
\item $5$
\item $\cfrac{1}{4}$
\item $\cfrac{1}{5}$
\item $\cfrac{1}{6}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Is there a simple way to get the same number of items in each column?

Comment: Add `\vphantom{\cfrac14}` -> `\item $1\vphantom{\cfrac14}$`, etc.

Comment: The `\cfrac` command -- generally used for typesetting continued fractions -- inserts even more vertical space than `\dfrac` ("display style `\frac`") does. This choice contributes to making the lines look rather unbalanced. Could you live with using `\tfrac` ("text style `\frac`") throughout?

Comment: @karlkoeller That works for this, but I'd like something more automatic. Especially if I have several different item heights, this would be cumbersome, and might need to be redone entirely if I decide on 3 columns instead of 2

Comment: @Mico: This was my MWE. I really don't care about fractions. My list might have single numbers, matrices, integrals . . . anything of different heights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create my own environment, say `myenumerate`, which inserts a strut with each `\item` to some predefined height and depth so it accommodates for the largest item. I've hardcoded it below to have a depth of `1\baselineskip` and span `3\baselineskip` (effectively `2\baselineskip` above the baseline):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{multicol,amsmath,etoolbox}
\newenvironment{myenumerate}
  {\enumerate% Regular enumerate environment
   \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}\rule[-\baselineskip]{0pt}{3\baselineskip}}}
  {\endenumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{myenumerate}
  \item $1$
  \item $2$
  \item $3$
  \item $4$
  \item $5$
  \item $\dfrac{1}{4}$
  \item $\dfrac{1}{5}$
  \item $\dfrac{1}{6}$
\end{myenumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The strut is inserted through a (local) redefinition of `\makelabel` - the macro responsible for setting the actual label formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the `tasks` package that I just learned about.

The package has the side effect that numbering increments horizontally rather than vertically, but that's fine with me. Also there are some limitations, like `tasks` environment can't be nested (but can contain `itemize` and other normal lists). I'm OK with both of those facts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task $1$
        \task $2$
        \task $3$
        \task $\frac{1}{4}$
        \task $5$
        \task $\frac{1}{5}$
        \task $4$
        \task $\frac{1}{6}$
    \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]