# Row wise list environment

Tags: multicol

Let us consider the following example :

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\item Text
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This produces :

[image]

I want to get the following list environment using the same package 'multicol

'

[image]

Is there any way  to do this ?

Comment: You should try [Horizontal enumeration in multiple columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89603/5764).