# Horizontal enumeration in multiple columns with custom labels

Tags: enumerate, labels, columns

I have a question based on what I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/horizontal-enumeration-in-multiple-columns). I was hoping to change the labels of these items from numbers to a word followed by a number.
In particular, I would like to see:

```
Problem 1: stuff here    Problem 2: next thing's stuff here
```

etc.

as I use each `\item` rather than just:

```
1. stuff here
2. next thing's stuff here
```

etc.

For a normal `enumerate` you would use `[label=Problem \arabic*:]` attached to the declaration, but that doesn't seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89612/11232) from the link provided in the question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab Problem~\latexitem}Problem~\latexitem}}  %%<<-- just add Problem~ here
 {\endinparaenum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbedenum}{3}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{tabbedenum}

\bigskip

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{inparaenum}
\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\end{inparaenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now with `tasks` package from [Clemens answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89611/11232)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

% \NewTasks[options]{name}[separator](default number of columns)
% all arguments except {name} are optional
\NewTasks[counter-format=Problem~tsk[1]:,label-width=5.5em,label-format=\bfseries]{tabbedEnum}[\item](3)

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabbedEnum}
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
 \item text
\end{tabbedEnum}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: problems]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=Problem (\arabic*)]
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite; the other method has nice column spacing associated with it that I would like to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution based on the `shortlst` package, with a small patch: I introduced $3$ keys: `nc` (number of columns; $3$ by default), `il` (interline stretch, 1 by default, may be useful in case of very high formulae) and `ls` (the value of \labelsep, 0.6em by default). It also uses `xkeyval` and `setspace`.

An \item, if larger than one column, will occupy as many columns as necessary. I introduce a `\paritem` command, that sets the item body in a \parbox that occupies a chosen number of columns (1 by default). It gives a way to control the number of columns that an item occupies.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{shortlst,setspace,xkeyval}%

\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\define@key{lex}{ls}[0.6em]{\setlength{\labelsep}{#1}}%%distance between label and item body
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%\setlength\labelsep{0.6em}
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,ls, #1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{\itshape Problem 0\hskip0.25em}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\setstretch{\@intln}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{shortenumerate}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
}%
\newcommand\paritem[2][1]{\item \parbox[t]{\dimexpr#1\shortitemwidth +(\labelwidth + \labelsep + \itemindent)* \numexpr#1-1\relax\relax}{\setstretch{1}\leavevmode#2\strut\medskip}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\itshape Problem \arabic{enumi}.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\noindent Solve the following equations:
\begin{tabenumerate}[nc=3]
  \item Stuff here.
  \item Next thing’s stuff here. It requires 2 columns. \label{pb2}
  \item Stuff there.
  \paritem{Equation $4$ is another long equation in only one column. }
  \item Still stuff.
  \paritem[2] {\label{pb6} Equation $6$ is a second long equation. It stretches along two columns and no more.}
  \item A small problem.
  \item Equation $8$ is also a very very long equation, but its stretches ‘naturally’.

\end{tabenumerate}
We see by problems \ref{pb2} and \ref{pb6} that cross-references seem to work in this context.

\end{document} %
```

[image]