# Make multiline list items line up horizontally

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, lists

I'm trying to make a list in which each item has multiple lines, and I want the items to line up horizontally, like this:

```
1. this is the        2. and this is
   first item in         the second item
   the list
```

I've tried a bunch of different things, but what always ends up happening is that the first line of the second item lines up with the last line of the first item, like so:

```
1. this is the
   first item in
   the list 2. and this is
   the second item
```

Anyone have a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: Related, possible solution: [Multiple Choices Questions in 2 or 3 columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46687/3345)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  Also, in this case, the solution may very well depend on how you are creating the lists.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `tasks` package?  I've found it quite useful for something along the lines of what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the `tasks` package?  It can achieve something like what you're asking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

I'm trying to make a list in which each item has multiple lines, and I want the items to line up horizontally, like this:
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task  
 this is the        
   first item in      
   the list      this is the        
   first item in      
   the list      this is the        
   first item in      
   the list      this is the        
   first item in      
   the list           
\task and this is the second itme.and this is the second itme.and this is the second itme.and this is the second itme.and this is the second itme.
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]